# NextJS server-side debug won't start using VS Code

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, next.js, next.js14

Since upgrading to Next.js version 14.0.4 from version 12, I cannot start server-side debugging in VS Code on Windows. Everything works when I manually run `npm run dev`, or `npm run build` && `npm run start`. But when I click on "Next.js: debug server-side" in the VS Code "Run and Debug" tab, I only see the following output in terminal:

```
Debugger attached.

> dev
> next dev
```

The server never starts. I should be seeing some output about the next.js version and the server being started like when I run `npm run dev`. When I go to the `http://localhost:3000` in the browser, I get an ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED. I don't know if this is related, but I can see this exception when I select to break on all exceptions:

[image]

Here is my launch.json file:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Next.js: debug server-side",
            "type": "node-terminal",
            "request": "launch",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}\\src",
            "command": "npm run dev"
        },
        {
            "name": "Next.js: debug client-side",
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}\\src",
            "url": "http://localhost:3000"
        },
        {
            "name": "Next.js: debug full stack",
            "type": "node-terminal",
            "request": "launch",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}\\src",
            "command": "npm run dev",
            "serverReadyAction": {
                "pattern": "started server on .+, url: (https?://.+)",
                "uriFormat": "%s",
                "action": "debugWithChrome"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

And here's my `package.json` section:

```
{
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "next dev",
        "build": "next build",
        "export": "next build && next export",
        "start": "next start",
        "lint": "next lint",
        "test": "jest --watch",
        "storybook": "storybook dev -p 6006",
        "build-storybook": "storybook build"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "classnames": "^2.3.1",
        "js-cookie": "^3.0.1",
        "next": "^14.0.4",
        "next-intl": "^3.0.1",
        "react": "^18.2.0",
        "react-animate-height": "^3.0.5",
        "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
        "react-gtm-module": "^2.0.11",
        "react-svg": "^16.1.31",
        "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
        "tsyringe": "^4.8.0",
        "uuid": "^9.0.1"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^7.5.3",
        "@storybook/addon-interactions": "^7.5.3",
        "@storybook/addon-links": "^7.5.3",
        "@storybook/addon-onboarding": "^1.0.8",
        "@storybook/blocks": "^7.5.3",
        "@storybook/nextjs": "^7.5.3",
        "@storybook/react": "^7.5.3",
        "@storybook/testing-library": "^0.2.2",
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^6.1.4",
        "@testing-library/react": "^14.0.0",
        "@types/jest": "^29.5.6",
        "@types/js-cookie": "^3.0.2",
        "@types/node": "^18.7.1",
        "@types/react": "^18.0.17",
        "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.6",
        "@types/react-gtm-module": "^2.0.2",
        "eslint": "^8.51.0",
        "eslint-config-next": "^13.5.6",
        "jest": "^29.7.0",
        "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.7.0",
        "sass": "^1.54.5",
        "storybook": "^7.4.6",
        "typescript": "^5.2.2"
    }
}
```